# Discord Bot doesn't log in on startup

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.io

I'm trying to figure out why my Discord bot doesn't log in as before.

[image]

As in the image I'm trying to log in, but nothing happens... No errors, or anything. I updated the node version to 9.2.1 and now when I check for version it says 5.6.0. Any clues about what's going on?

Also I tried to reinstall node and winston module and it says "npm WARN CheckRank@1.0.0 No repository field", nor license field.

Comment: You're checking your `npm` version, not `node`. `node --version` should output `9.2.1`

Comment: My bad, yes it is 9.2.1

Answer (score 2):

If you’re using Discord.io, which it looks like you are, simply enter the following into the console while in the bot directory:

```
 npm install https://github.com/woor/discord.io/tarball/gateway_v6
```

The reason your bot crashes is because Discord.io has not been updated to the new Discord API v6 Gateway, and such the community has to rely on itself for a fix.